# List all Play subscriptions

Tags: google-api, google-play, in-app-subscription

Is there any API or script to get back a list of all live Google Play subscriptions for a given app? ie a data form of what's shown on the Play developer console under Subscriptions.

Stripe, for example, has an explicit [list subscriptions API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_subscriptions), but I can't find the equivalent for Play.

**UPDATE:** Since writing this, I've enquired to official sources and I can confirm there is indeed no API to retrieve all of your subscriptions. Certainly surprising, but that's where it stands.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Still not possible to my knowledge. A bizarre omission.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html) on the device you can use the [getPurchases()](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases) method returns live subscriptions.

On the server there is the Google Developer API [Purchases.subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions) REST Object.

Comment: Isn't that just for one user though? "This method returns the current un-consumed products owned by the user". I'm trying to get all subscriptions for all users.